# Writing file for each process of MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, output, mpi, hpc

I have written this part of the code in order to have a file for each rank and see its content. The question I have is that how can I extend this code to work for an arbitrary size. Here, as I was running with 4 cores; I already knew my size so I wrote my code with 4 if conditions which I think there should be a better way to handle this for a higher number of processes.

```
string local_string = to_string(rank) + base;
ofstream output{ local_string };
if (local_string == "0.txt") {
    for (int i = 0; i < N;i++) {
        output << data[i] << endl; 
    }
}

if (local_string == "1.txt") {
    for (int i = 0; i < N;i++) {
        output <<data[i] << endl;
    }
}

if (local_string == "2.txt") {
    for (int i = 0; i < N;i++) {
        output << data[i] << endl;
    }
}

if (local_string == "3.txt") {
    for (int i = 0; i < N;i++) {
        output << data[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are running with multiple processes in parallel you do not actually need to specify the conditions:

```
string local_string = to_string(rank) + base;
read the file with the name local_string
and print the content of the file to the output
```

If it for debugging purposes you might to want to add a condition so that you only print the file of the process with a certain rank:

```
    if(rank == rank_to_print_the_file){
       string local_string = to_string(rank) + base;
       read the file with the name local_string
       and print the content of the file to the output
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `MPI_Barrier` before writing to files will eliminates us to come with the idea of if the condition for each process

Comment: what do you need a barrier ?

Comment: Because when I used Barrier before starting to write into files, I deleted if conditions and created files were the same. In fact, they were in the order that I want: like 0.txt contains the data of rank 0 and 1.txt contains the data of rank 1

Comment: Did you try to write without the barrier and conditions?

Comment: Oh it is strange. now that you mentioned I tried commenting MPI_Barrier and it was OK. But, I remember that without Barrier, there was problem in ordring

Comment: You can added just to be "safe" but I don't think you need.